# Interpretation of external regression coefficient in linear regression with ARMA errors

Tags: time-series, arima

I am fitting a linear regression model $y_t = b\times x_t + u_t$ with ARMA errors $u_t$. Is the interpretation of $b$ the same as in usual linear regression?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is.

This hangs crucially on the fact that you are running a *regression with AR(I)MA errors*, not an *ARIMAX model*, where coefficients are much harder to interpret.

I strongly recommend [Rob Hyndman's blog post on "The ARIMAX model muddle"](http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/arimax/), which has also been recommended before on CV - [previous questions and answers pointing to this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=ARIMAX+model+muddle) may also be helpful.